# Stylus|CSS каждое слово выше на ХХpx

Tags: css, ms-word, stylus

Есть предложение в теге span или div.

```
<span>Есть предложение в теге span или div.</span>
```

Можно ли с Stylus или CSS задать стиль для отдельного слова, наподобие `span:nth-child(3)`:

```
span:nth-child(3)
position relative
top -4px
```

Версия CSS, для тех, кто stylus не знает...

```
span:nth-child(3) {
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
}
```

Возможно, как-то задать `display: table-cell;` и для table-cell задать свой стиль? Может, word-spacing специальный...?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский 
Спасибо))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать:

::nth-word()

::first-word

::last-word

::nth-last-word()

**UPDATE:**

Виноват - эти теги не работают. Оказывается, это были просто предложения для внесения в будущую версию css.

Остается только `javascript`.

```
<body>

<span class="ladder">Есть предложение в теге span или div.</span>

<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var words = $('.ladder').text().split(" ");
        $('.ladder').empty();
        var top = 0;
        $.each(words, function (i, v) {
            var word = $('<span>').text(v + ' ').css('position', 'relative').css('top', '-' + top + 'px');
            $('.ladder').append(word);
            top += 2;
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
```

[Работающая страница](http://test.kagg.eu/so/630036.html) на моем тестовом сайте.

Comment: `::nth-word()` !??
Спасибо, но разве в чистом CSS это допустимо? или это библиотека js какая-то подключается?

Comment: Исправил ответ . Сделал рабочий пример на javascript.

Comment: Cпасибо! Способ хороший, но мне важно на css сделать, или, хотя бы, прикреплять js как библиотеку, что бы делать изменения в самом css.

Comment: Мне кажется, нет способа сделать это на css.